# what is the function of Current Source in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

The voltage across current source is due to current itself or due to the circuit within which it is present.

Comment: What??? You've serious problems then....

Comment: An ideal current source will provide whatever voltage difference is necessary to push the specified current through the circuit. But, you have a false dichotomy in your question - the answer is not either/or, but 'both'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this better take the fluid mechanics analogy.Consider a pipe to be a conductor and the pressure across it to be the voltage difference and water flow to be current.Now consider a situation where there is water flowing from through the pipe,it is a matter of fact that if water is flowing there has to be some pressure difference between the ends of the pipe.The more the pressure difference faster the water flows in other words more water flows.As it is obvious that water and pressure are two different entities they are independent of each other in normal cases.But when it comes to flow one cannot exist without the other(as mentioned before),but yeah we can have water stagnant in the pipe without pressure,and so referring to your question the stagnant water is nothing but electrons moving in random directions.Now to answer your question,imagine what if if you'd place ur finger in the way of flowing water or any obstruction of that sort, there's an additional pressure created which adds to the already existing pressure. In electrical analogy I'm talking about the resistance,so bigger the obstacle greater is the pressure difference. So when you talk of a conductor it a pipe with stagnant water and as current is rate at which charges flow it is obvious that there has to be some pressure difference between the ends the end of the conductor which may be due to the power supply or external circuit and so current is due the voltage.Hope you can figure out the other points regarding this using same analogy. Hope this answers our question.